# Adding `firebase` node package breaks Next.js SSR hosted on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I have a Next.js page hosted on firebase. It has one SSR page that loads firebase admin SDK as

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({..}) => {
  console.log("Init Firebase admin App");
  if (admin.apps.length == 0) {
    admin.initializeApp();
  }
```

and everything works fine.

As soon as I add `"firebase": "^10.8.0",` to `package.json`, the firebase-deployed site crashes during SSR with `'The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using ...`.

However, the logs show that `Init Firebase admin App` was logged before the crash.

Any ideas what could cause it?

Edit: An MRE can be found [here](https://github.com/nidegen/firebase-nextjs-mre). Not the last commit introduces the breaking change.

The error happens when rendering `/invite/[id].tsx`

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK is published "firebase-admin" not "firebase".  The one you're using now is for web browser clients, not nodejs backends.  It's not clear to me why you need to use both in the same process.

Comment: I know. I use "firebase-admin" for SSRed pages, but want to add "firebase" for client-side auth.

Comment: Maybe you would like to show a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) of a project that fails in the way you're describing.  We should be able to duplicate the behavior using the code and instructions you provide.  Outside the one function you're showing, we can't see what all you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

"The default Firebase app does not exist" error you're encountering in your Next.js application deployed on Firebase.

**Understanding the Error:**

This error arises when the Firebase Admin SDK is attempting to access the default Firebase app, which hasn't been initialized yet within the context of your Next.js SSR (Server-Side Rendering) page.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // ... your Firebase project configuration
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  // Initialize Firebase only if not already initialized
  if (!admin.apps.length) {
    try {
      admin.initializeApp({
        credential: await admin.credential.cert({
          // Load credentials from environment variables or secure storage
          privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY,
          projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
          // ... other credentials
        }),
        databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL,
      });
      console.log('Firebase Admin initialized successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing Firebase Admin:', error);
      // Handle potential initialization errors gracefully
    }
  }

  // ... your page logic using Firebase Admin SDK

  return {
    props: {
      // ... your page data
    },
  };
};
```

**Additional:**

If you encounter further challenges, provide more details about your implementation, including relevant code snippets, error messages, and server-side logs.

Consider utilizing a dependency management tool like yarn or npm to manage your Node.js packages effectively and avoid version conflicts.
By following these steps and carefully considering your Firebase Admin SDK initialization and credential setup, you should be able to resolve the "The default Firebase app does not exist" error and achieve successful Firebase Admin usage within your Next.js SSR page.